# Find out what line of code my app is currently running in Android Studio's debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.1, android-debug

When I'm running an app in debug mode with Android Studio, is there a way that I can find out what line of code is currently being processed? By this I mean, is there a tool that works kind of like setting a breakpoint, but you don't have to set a breakpoint - you can just find out at any point in time what line of code is being executed?

The reason for this, is that sometimes you may want to debug intermittent hangs in your app. If your running in debug mode, and your app hangs, it would be useful to immediately find out what line of code it last processed, without having to plan ahead by setting breakpoints or trace calls

Comment: Got anything on this ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur not yet sorry.